# How to make a sidebar menu fixed, but floated on the right side

Tags: css, html, web

I have been at this for a while and I am wondering how to make a side menu stay in the same place, but stay floating on the right side.  When ever I use the fixed element it all ways pulls my sidebar from right to left.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set sidebar position to fixed. Set the height and width you wish and the set the `right` css property to 0. That should work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to Specify position like `top` and `left` like:

```
div#myDIV
{
     position:fixed;
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     left:10px;
     top:100px;
}
```

See this example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed

Answer (score 0):

try `right:0`

```
.cont
{
     position:fixed;
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     right:0px;
     top:100px;
     background:#999;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6L6wj/

Answer (score 0):

I would also consider to use the z-index property:

```
#yourdiv {
     position:fixed;
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     right:10px;
     top:10px;
     z-index: 10;
}
```

Remember to set the other contaner to

```
#maincontainer {
     position:relative;
     z-index: 1;
}
```